# Using Parcelable model classes outside Android, with a Parcelable wrapper

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I would like to create some model classes that implement Android's Parcelable interface, but I want the classes to be usable outside Android. I thought about implementing a wrapper for all these model classes (they are serialized in the same way, with Google Protocol Buffers internally), but I am not sure how to do it.

Say I have an interface Model, and an implementing class ModelImpl. Currently, Model extends Parcelable, but I would like to decouple Model and ModelImpl from Parcelable, and have a ParcelWrapper instead. Preferably, this should all be type safe and nice. Any pointers as to how to approach this problem?

If I come across a solution, I'll post it here, of course.

Thanks! :)

Comment: so you want to use the parcelable functionality or just be able to compile the classes outside of android?

Comment: one solution would be to extend a proxy class that has a definition for android involving parcelable, and another definition outside android that does not. (2 classes with the same name and package defined in 2 places, one for android, one for java)

Comment: another solution would be using annotations to inject the extends parcelable at compile time

Comment: @meredrica: Just be able to compile and use the value classes outside of Android. Basically, so the same model can be used on the mobile phone and, say, a server.

Comment: @njzk2: Annotations and reflection, you mean? The solution with two classes with the same qualified name seams somewhat "unclean". It means the library wouldn't compile without this class being present in some way, a sort of reverse dependency (unless I've misunderstood something). But thanks for the suggestion!

I've played around with using something like ParcelWrapper<Model> or ParcelWrapper<ModelImpl>, but no luck, yet.

Comment: no, annotation and code injection (i know it is possible, but never actually did it)

Comment: else, may be a decorator that would implement parcelable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the decorator pattern. So now I've got:

- Model, the interface that defines the public methods I need.
- ModelImpl, the actual implementing model class (which uses Google Protocol Buffers for serialisation)
- ModelParcelDecorator, which implements Model and Parcelable, and takes an instance of an implementation of Model and stores it as reference, delegating all methods from the Model interface to this instance. ModelParcelDecorator uses the protocol buffers serialisation mechanism directly, so I don't need to serialise into a Parcel and back manually.

Model and ModelImpl can now reside in their own library, and be used outside Android.

Unfortunately, I needed to write a decorator for each of my model classes, but this is the best solution I found until now. If I find something better, I will post it here.

Comment: Since you're extending the interface it is actually the adapter pattern; the decorator pattern doesn't change the interface.